# customize swagger-ui by adding a simple sidebar in the html

Tags: javascript, html, css, swagger

So I'm trying to make a navigation panel sidebar on the swagger-ui front page. I'm using the http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/ simple sidebar. I tried putting that code ( + the css file) in the dist folder of swagger-ui and then, in my dist/index.html,  I tried to add it but it's not displaying properly. I think this is because swagger content is being generated from different templates. I just want my sidebar to be there on the main page.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

[image]

dist/index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Swagger UI</title>
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
      <link href='css/typography.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
      <link href='css/reset.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
      <link href='css/screen.css' media='screen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
      <link href='css/reset.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
      <link href='css/print.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
      <link href='css/bootstrap.min.css' media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
      <link href="css/simple-sidebar.css" media='print' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>

      <script src='lib/object-assign-pollyfill.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/jquery.slideto.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/jquery.wiggle.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/jquery.ba-bbq.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/handlebars-2.0.0.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/js-yaml.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/lodash.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/backbone-min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='swagger-ui.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/highlight.9.1.0.pack_extended.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/jsoneditor.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/marked.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src='lib/swagger-oauth.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

      <!-- Some basic translations -->
      <!-- <script src='lang/translator.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->
      <!-- <script src='lang/ru.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->
      <!-- <script src='lang/en.js' type='text/javascript'></script> -->

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
          var url="http://localhost:8081/instagram.yml";


          var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
          if (url && url.length > 1) {
            url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
          } else {
            url = "http://localhost:8081/instagram.yml";
          }

          hljs.configure({
            highlightSizeThreshold: 5000
          });

          // Pre load translate...
          if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
            window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
          }

          window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({

            url: url,
            dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
            supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch'],
            onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
              if(typeof initOAuth == "function") {
                initOAuth({
                  clientId: "your-client-id",
                  clientSecret: "your-client-secret-if-required",
                  realm: "your-realms",
                  appName: "your-app-name",
                  scopeSeparator: ",",
                  additionalQueryStringParams: {}
                });
              }

              if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
                window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
              }
            },
            onFailure: function(data) {
              log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
            },
            docExpansion: "none",
            jsonEditor: false,
            defaultModelRendering: 'schema',
            showRequestHeaders: false
          });

          window.swaggerUi.load();     

          function log() {
            if ('console' in window) {
              console.log.apply(console, arguments);
            }
          }
        });


      </script>

    </head>

    <body class="swagger-section">
    <div id='header'>
      <div class="swagger-ui-wrap">
        <a id="logo" href="http://swagger.io">swagger</a>
        <form id='api_selector'>
          <div class='input'><input placeholder="http://example.com/api" id="input_baseUrl" name="baseUrl" type="text"/></div>
          <div class='input'><input placeholder="api_key" id="input_apiKey" name="apiKey" type="text"/></div>
          <div class='input'><a id="explore" href="#">Explore</a></div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
       <ul class="sidebar-nav">
         <li class="sidebar-brand">
           <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="#">Overview</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="#">Events</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="#">About</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="#">Services</a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="#">Contact</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>

    <div id="message-bar" class="swagger-ui-wrap">&nbsp;</div>

    <div id="swagger-ui-container" class="swagger-ui-wrap"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I would suggest checking your developer tools dashboard in your browser and inspect the sidebar elements -- maybe the simple-sidebar CSS files are being overridden by your other CSS files.

Comment: @TimChen Yes it is, by reset.css. No idea what that is. The actual contents are being generated by swager's own templates/handlebars. So Maybe I have to add my sidebar there? Not sure

Comment: CSS rankings is sometimes weird. However, if you use in-line CSS it will trump any other CSS. But since it's a file I don't think that'll be reasonable/readable. Try copying all of your sidebar CSS into the HTML page, using `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The index.html file is missing:

- A div with id `sidebar-wrapper` containing the side bar
- A div with id `page-content-wrapper` containing what is on the right of the side bar
- A div with id `wrapper` containing both `sidebar-wrapper` and `page-content-wrapper`

Here's an example (full working repo here: https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html)

```
    <body class="swagger-section">
    <div id='header'>
          <div class="swagger-ui-wrap">
            <a id="logo" href="http://swagger.io"><img class="logo__img" alt="swagger" height="30" width="30" src="images/logo_small.png" /><span class="logo__title">swagger</span></a>
            <!-- Bootstrap Simple Sidebar: Toggle button -->
            <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
            <form id='api_selector'>
              <div class='input'><input placeholder="http://example.com/api" id="input_baseUrl" name="baseUrl" type="text"/></div>
              <div id='auth_container'></div>
              <div class='input'><a id="explore" class="header__btn" href="#" data-sw-translate>Explore</a></div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap Simple Sidebar: Global wrapper, contains sidebar and page -->
    <div id="wrapper">
      <!-- Bootstrap Simple Sidebar: Sidebar -->
      <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
          <ul class="sidebar-nav">
              <li class="sidebar-brand">
                  <a href="#">
                      Start Bootstrap
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Overview</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Events</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Bootstrap Simple Sidebar: Page wrapper -->
      <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div id="message-bar" class="swagger-ui-wrap" data-sw-translate>&nbsp;</div>
        <div id="swagger-ui-container" class="swagger-ui-wrap"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Simple Sidebar: Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>
  </body>
```

The repo https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html provide 2 branches:

- v1.0_header_in_page: The SwaggerUI green header is in the page and not fixed
  [image]
- v1.1_header_above_sidebar: The SwaggerUI green header is above the sidebar and fixed
  [image]

I had to modify some css and handlebar template to solve to bugs due to bootstrap integration in swagger ui (see commits list for details).

**Full step by step instructions**

First and foremost: never edit files in `dist` folder directly, you have to work with source files in `src`:

- css:

  - You can add your own css to `src/main/html/css/`
  - SwaggerUI's css are build using less files in `src/main/less`, once compiled the css files go to `src/main/html/css/`
- html:

  - `src/main/template contains handlebar HTML templates (it's everything except the header and footer of SwaggerUI)
  - `src/main/html`contains the main html file (index.html)

Each step correspond to a commit in the [example repository](https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html).

*Project init*

- Clone Swagger UI repository: `git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui`
- Download dependencies:

  - `cd swagger-ui`
  - `npm install`
- Start dev mode: `gulp dev`

  - This build the application, launch a web server on port 8080. If modifications are done to the code, the browser will reload automatically

*Adding simple-sidebar.css and bootstrap.min.css to the project ([commit](https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html/commit/4ef712119e155ab70a2cef2829eba68de8af919d))*

- Copy `simple-sidebar.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` to `src/main/html/css/`
- Modify `src/main/html/index.html` to add a reference to these 2 css files after swagger-ui css:

*Add bootstrap sidebar ([commit](https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html/commit/efcc9081c561f44cd096ddcd12ecaabbac1d0fe8))*

- Modify `src/main/html/index.html`:

  - Enclose all components which are in the body in a `<div id="page-content-wrapper">` div
  - Enclose  in a `<div id="wrapper">` div
  - Add the sidebar (`<div id="sidebar-wrapper"> ... </div>`) on top of `<div id="wrapper">`
  - Add the Menu Toggle Script just before `</body>`

Once this is done, you have:

- A functionnal sidebar
- A Swagger UI header on the right on the sidebar
- Few css bugs like:

  - Green background header wrong size
  - White padding around the page (on the right of the sidebar)
  - Swagger ui main container too large

*Fix Swagger UI container width ([commit](https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html/commit/95988527f215e53adb2eb1cfa8659da8f4a4fe60))*

- To fix swagger container width you need to modify `src/main/template/main.handlebars`:

  - This file is the main template containing the info section, the div where the API description will go and the footer
  - The div `id='resources_container'` use a class `container`, rename this class to `sw-container`

*Fix white padding around page ([commit](https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html/commit/2dfe5fc719a890166aa611c35663159c6425283f))*

- The white padding comes from the `` file:

  - You just need to remove both `padding` in `#page-content-wrapper` on line 47 and 121

*Fix header green background size*
  - To fix this bug you have to modify a `screen.less` in `src/main/less/`
  - This folder contains all less files which will be used to create css files for Swagger UI
  - I choose to remove height:23 and slightly change padding to solve this bug

Once this is donne you have (branch [v1.0_header_in_page](https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html/tree/v1.0_header_in_page)):

- A functionnal sidebar
- A Swagger ui on the right of the sidebar
- A correct display

*Move SwaggerUI header on top and fix it ([commit](https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html/commit/d312990f6c51cf3789225d66bc6d077a74622e87), branch [v1.1_header_above_sidebar](https://github.com/arno-di-loreto/stackoverflow-38377821-customize-swagger-ui-by-adding-a-simple-sidebar-in-the-html/tree/v1.1_header_above_sidebar))*

- To put the header on top modify `src/main/html/index.html`, move the  `<div id='header'>` just before the `<div id="wrapper">`
- To fix it modify `src/main/less/screen.less` to add these values to `#header`:

  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 100000;
  width: 100%;
- To avoid content to be hidden behind the header modify `src/main/html/css/simple-sidebar.css` to add `padding-top: 50px;` to `#wrapper`

Comment: thanks man, just what I needed! How did you know that you needed to modify the screen.less and handlebars. I'm trying to learn because I'm new to all this

Comment: I've added a step by step instructions to make it easier to understand. I already knew how to modify swagger-ui :-). But to find the css bugs I use developer tools available in chrome or firefox to see where the problems come from.

Comment: Thanks! There seems to be another issue with the header.  I noticed odd layout behavior which causes the widgets to move around when I flip between APIs. This is causedwhen window.swaggerUi.load(); is called, everytime I click on the side-bar elements. Here's the issue: http://giphy.com/gifs/l0MYEhoVvCWPPTQre

Comment: The GitHub URL is not showing can you add the same.